# Pullbacks and fixed parts of linear systems

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal variety over a field.
Let $\Lambda$ be a nonempty linear system of divisors on $X$.
The *fixed part* of $\Lambda$ is defined to be the effective divisor
$$
\operatorname{Fix}\Lambda=\min_{D\in\Lambda}D,
$$
where the minimum is taken in each component.

Let $Y$ be another normal variety and $f\colon Y\to X$ be a morphism.
The *pullback* of $\Lambda$ is the linear system on $Y$
$$
f^*\Lambda = \{f^* D\mid D\in\Lambda\}.
$$

**Question.**
Is it true that
$$
\operatorname{Fix} f^*\Lambda = f^*(\operatorname{Fix}\Lambda)?
$$

**My attempt:**
I proved that $\operatorname{Fix} f^*\Lambda \ge f^*(\operatorname{Fix}\Lambda).$
Indeed, for any $D\in\Lambda$, we have $f^*D\ge f^*(\operatorname{Fix}\Lambda)$ since $D\ge \operatorname{Fix}\Lambda$.

How can we show the convese?
Is there a counter exmple?
I cannot proceed here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider, for instance, the pencil of lines on the plane through a fixed point. It has no fixed part, but if $f$ is the embedding of a line throguh this point, the pullback has fixed part.